# Angular Material: Can't find Typography classes

Tags: css, typography, angular-material

I can't find the css classes demoed in the example website here:
https://material.angularjs.org/#/CSS/typography

I have bower installed angular-material, and I have version 0.8.3

I found the classes I am looking for here in their github:
https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/core/style/typography.scss

But I can't find a compiled version for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like typography CSS classes were added **since** the [0.8.3 tag of the bower-material repository](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/tree/v0.8.3) (in the [6af154](https://github.com/angular/material/commit/6af1546da48aa335ca65ff32f09e2d3b69d0a2d9) commit). They showed up in the [v0.8.3-master-6af1546 tag](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/tree/v0.8.3-master-6af1546) but bower is still probably pulling the initial v0.8.3 release.

A **temporary workaround** is to hardcode your bower angular material dependency to a tag that does include the typography styles e.g.:

`"angular-material": "0.8.3-master-ffd299d"`

Obviously, you wouldn't want to leave it like this long term if you ever wanted to get updates.  I'd expect the 0.8.4 release of Angular Material will include the typography styles at which point it **should** work to change your `bower.json` back to something like:

`"angular-material": "0.8.x"`

Answer (score 0):

As I know this is temporary (hopefully this is coming in 0.9.0) I just downloaded the CSS file directly from github, dropped into my vendor folder and then imported it in my main less/css file.

Once I update to 0.9.0. I'll simply remove the import reference.

Be warned though, even this doesn't provided you with the full typography set, or at least some of them still aren't rendering properly when inside other containers (but that might just be my bad HTML skills!)